# How do i download a file using AJAX in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, download, xmlhttprequest

I need to download a file from a different server (from Documentum) through a VBCS application. If i put the URL of the document into postman and provide basic authentication and then click on send and download, I am able to download the document but when i try to do it through AJAX and javascript, the document does not get downloaded but i can see the contents of the document in the response of my GET call. Following is the code that i have written -

```
     var xhrdoc = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhrdoc.open("GET", docURL1);
 


     xhrdoc.setRequestHeader("Accept", "*/*");
    // xhrdoc.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
     xhrdoc.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/octet-stream");
     xhrdoc.setRequestHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment");
     xhrdoc.setRequestHeader("Authorization","Basic "+btoa(username+":"+password));
     console.log("Log:docURL",xhrdoc.status);
    
 // window.location.href = docURL1;

     xhrdoc.send();

    

    xhrdoc.onload = function () {
  console.log("inside onload for get doc");
   console.log("Log: inside getdoc",xhrdoc.status, "Status");
  console.log("Log: inside getdoc",xhrdoc.responseURL,"ResponseURL");
  console.log("Log inside get doc response text",xhrdoc.responseText);
  console.log("log inside response ", xhrdoc.response);
```

Any help will be really appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What is "a VBCS application"? (I expect this code will not work in browser due to CORS/same origin)

Comment: Visual Builder Cloud Services - it is just a low code software for development of applications. But if there was an issue with CORS, it should not have returned the contents of the document as a response to me also right? But I am able to see the contents when I print them in the console.

Comment: If you see the file content being downloaded, but the browser blocks access to the data, then it is most likely a CORS issue.   I've not used Oracle VBCS, but the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/app-builder-cloud/visual-builder-developer/configure-authentication-service-connections.html#GUID-708DFE9D-9055-4B24-AF3C-D1D6312E539B) says CORS must be configured on the backend for it to work.

Comment: But if it was a CORS issue, shouldnt it throw an error? When i print the status of my GET call, im getting it as 200 only, so i assume its a successfule call.